# How can I convert my dataset for Tensorflow.keras.model.fit()

Tags: tensorflow2.0

I have a list of tuple, looks like below:

```
[
    (
        9999                          #  label
        ,[1.23, 3.12, -0.232, ....]   #  a list of float numbers
    ),
    ( 
        ...
    )
]
```

How can I convert it to `x`, `y` that be used by `tensorflow.keras.model.fit(x, y, ...)`?
I use Tensorflow 2.0, python 3.x

Can I do it without using pandas or numpy?